# Dynamic Sql- Issue with the active field search criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

i am creating a dynamic sql query for search in a table `tblEmployees`. In `tblEmployees` I have a field called `active` so I want that if we are providing active as 1 with other parameters  then it should search the records where active=1 and if we are not providing active to any value i mean neither 1 nor 0 then it should search with other parameters which i have defined in the query.

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmployees2
(
    EmployeeID       SMALLINT IDENTITY(1001,1) NOT NULL,
    EmployeeName     NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Department       NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Designation      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    JoiningDate      DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Salary           DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    [Description]    NVARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    active           Tinyint NULL 
)

INSERT INTO tblEmployees
(EmployeeName, Department, Designation, 
 JoiningDate, Salary, [Description],active) 
VALUES    
('John Smith', 'IT Research', 'Research Analyst', 
 '02/08/2005', 23000.00, 'Analyst since 2005',1)

INSERT INTO tblEmployees
(EmployeeName, Department, Designation, 
 JoiningDate, Salary, [Description],active) 
VALUES    
('John Micheal', 'IT Operations', 'Manager', 
 '07/15/2007', 15000.00, NULL,0)

INSERT INTO tblEmployees
(EmployeeName, Department, Designation, 
 JoiningDate, Salary, [Description],active) 
VALUES    
('Will Smith', 'IT Support', 'Manager', 
 '05/20/2006', 13000.00, 'Joined last year as IT Support Manager',1)
```

and the dynamic sql--

```
/* Input Parameters */
Declare
@EmployeeName NVarchar(100),
@Department NVarchar(50),
@Designation NVarchar(50),
@StartDate DateTime,
@EndDate DateTime,
@Salary    Decimal(10,2),
@active tinyint

set @active=1--------------if active is 1 then it returns result where active=1 and if we are not providing
                          --any value neither 1 nor 0 then it should return both active=1 and active=0
set @EmployeeName='joh'
    /* Variable Declaration */
    Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 
    /* Build the Transact-SQL String with the input parameters */ 
    Set @SQLQuery = 'Select * From tblEmployees where (1=1) ' 
    /* check for the condition and build the WHERE clause accordingly */
    if @active=1   
    set @SQLQuery=@active + ' And (active = @active)'

If @EmployeeName Is Not Null 
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (EmployeeName LIKE '''+ '%' + @EmployeeName + '%' + ''')'

If @Department Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (Department = @Department)' 

If @Designation Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (Designation = @Designation)'

If @Salary Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (Salary >= @Salary)'

If (@StartDate Is Not Null) AND (@EndDate Is Not Null)
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (JoiningDate 
     BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)'
/* Specify Parameter Format for all input parameters included 
 in the stmt */
Set @ParamDefinition =      ' @EmployeeName NVarchar(100),
            @Department NVarchar(50),
            @Designation NVarchar(50),
            @StartDate DateTime,
            @EndDate DateTime,
            @Salary    Decimal(10,2),
            @active tinyint'
/* Execute the Transact-SQL String with all parameter value's 
   Using sp_executesql Command */
Execute sp_Executesql     @SQLQuery, 
            @ParamDefinition, 
            @EmployeeName, 
            @Department, 
            @Designation, 
            @StartDate, 
            @EndDate,
            @Salary,
            @active

print @SQLQuery
```

Comment: Also can you explain what is wrong here? The code seems to do what you want. The SQL statement only checks the active flag if `@active = 1`. Did you perhaps mean to say `if @active IN (0,1)`? This would allow you to pass `NULL` and that column won't be considered as part of the query. As it is, if you `set @active = 0` then you will return both `active = 0` and `active = 1` since that clause isn't added to the query. But as I said, in addition to posting your code, explain the actual problem you have with the code.

Comment: @Aaron,yes it seems that it would work but i am getting this exception 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' And (active = @active)' to data type tinyint.'

Comment: In the future, please post the error message you're getting. Your question would have been answered about 17 minutes earlier if you hadn't forced us to parse all of your code and try to guess what might have gone wrong. http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Comment: Yes @Aaron..from onwards I'll provide appropriate message..yes it was my fault. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
set @SQLQuery=@active + ' And (active = @active)'
```

To this:

```
set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (active = @active)'
```

Forest for the trees?

Comment: Thank @Aaron now it is working for me. Thanks a lot for your effort.